# C# Check if window is loaded

Tags: c#, windows

I need to check if a window is loaded, and that it is in the taskbar. I already tested

```
            IntPtr blaha2 = FindWindow(null, "Tibia");
            if (blaha2 != null)
            {
                client = Tibia.Objects.Client.GetClients()[0];
            }
```

But the getClients() method doesn't get any Tibia clients.
Grateful for answer.

Comment: I've found the problem: You *should* be calling `FindWindow(null, "Femur");` ;)

Comment: If that other process is yours and you want to disable two processes running together you can send some message to the other process and kill the current process.

Answer (score 2):

Using FindWindow() would only make sense if the window belongs to another process.  Which explains why GetClients() doesn't return anything, it would only be able to return clients from *your* process.  This would be in general unsolvable unless this library has some kind of out-of-process support.  That's quite rare.